# 16x 2 LCD 4 bit mode Raspberry PI with python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I cannot get my 16x2 display to initialize in 4 bit mode, the top row just stays white.
8 bit mode works completely fine, i'm on the raspberry pi, in python.
My setup:
Rpi --> PCF7385 via I2C
pcf -- lcd
0  -- 4
1  -- 5
2  -- 6
3  -- 7
4  -- enable
5  -- rs
6  -- nc
7  -- nc
gnd -- rw

### first I call the init method:

```py
print("PCF Mode") 
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup((self.rs_pin, self.enable_pin), GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(self.rs_pin, 0)
GPIO.output(self.enable_pin, 0)
self.i2c = SMBus()
self.i2c.open(1)
self.__send_instructie(0x38)  # Function Set 8
self.__send_instructie(0x0C)  # Display on
self.__send_instructie(0x02)  # Cursor Home
```

the self_instructie method:

```py
def __send_instructie(byte)
    self.__set_data_bits(byte, rs=0)
```

the set_data_bits method:

```py
            Hnibble = (byte >> 4) | 0x10  # enable high
            if rs: # depending on instruction or character make rs high or low
                Hnibble | 0x20
            self.i2c.write_byte(self.adres, Hnibble) # write to pcf
            # enable pulse
            sleep(40 / 1000000)  # 40 us break
            self.i2c.write_byte(self.adres, (Hnibble ^ 0x10))  # enable LOW
            sleep(40 / 1000000)  # 40 us pauze
            Lnibble = (byte & 0x0F) | 0x10  # Enable HIGH
            if rs:
                Lnibble | 0x20
            self.i2c.write_byte(self.adres, Lnibble)
            sleep(40 / 1000000)  # 40 us break
            self.i2c.write_byte(self.adres, (Lnibble ^ 0x10))  # enable LOW
            sleep(0.001)
```

i've tried sending 0x03 3 times in the beginning of the init method, nothing works
I'm expecting my display to clear, not showing the top line.

Comment: Statements like `Hnibble | 0x20` have no effect - you'd have to assign the result to a variable to actually do anything with it.  Perhaps you meant `Hnibble |= 0x20`.

Comment: omg ur a genious! Im a professional is making dumb mistakes xp, i have a blinking cursor now

Comment: After further investigation I'm still not able to get it to work, ive changed the above to |=